# How to add comma in the list having every element as set of values

Tags: java, string, list, collections

I have list with below mentioned values:

```
[cat mat bat, rat sat bat, wat fat got]
```

where **cat mat bat** is first element of the list.

I want to insert comma after every element in the set of list.
Example: cat,mat,bat should be first element.

Finally my list should look like:

```
[cat ,mat ,bat, 
rat ,sat ,bat,
wat ,fat ,got]
```

Comment: How about `String#replaceAll()` ?

Comment: _add comma in the list_, _set of values_ -  I don't see how this applies to the final list. It looks like a list of strings (wiith `" "` for some as last character) printed out. But in this case the comma comes from `AbstractCollection.toList()`.

Comment: Are you starting with a list of `String`s with each entry containing several blank-separated words (a `List<String>`).  Or is a list whose entries are lists of one-word strings (a `List<List<String>>`)?

Comment: @LuCio you probably mean `toString()`

Comment: @Holger Of course: `AbstractCollection.toString()` - Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can split elements by space, and flat-map the stream on the list:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("cat mat bat", "rat sat bat", "wat fat got");
List<String> result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result: `[cat, mat, bat, rat, sat, bat, wat, fat, got]`

Comment: my list is of type another class like List<ClassName> so i am not able to stream method.

Comment: @ShwetaSharma Please add the correct types to the question

Comment: @ShwetaSharma so your task is to insert commas into `ClassName` instances? How is that supposed to work?